# Conditionally replace values in one column/row with values from another row/column using dplyr

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, filter, replace

I am trying to conditionally replace values in one column/row with values from another column/row using `dplyr`.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
  id          colours tagl  TAGLFT grid
  <fct>       <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
  6391        B*/Y*   45820 45820  KL 
  6391        B*/Y*   45820 46272  KL
  8443        B*/Y*   46272 46272  SU
```

I am able to successfully replace within rows using this code:

```
updated<-df %>%
    mutate(tagl=ifelse(!tagl==TAGLFT, TAGLFT, tagl))
```

I look for any rows where `tagl==TAGLFT` and then replace `tagl` values with `TAGLFT` values. Then, if that condition is true (i.e., replacement has occurred), I need to also replace the `id` column with the correct `id` (these values are found in different rows).

Here is what I want:

```
  id          colours tagl  TAGLFT grid
  <fct>       <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
  6391        B*/Y*   45820 45820  KL 
  8443        B*/Y*   46272 46272  KL
  8443        B*/Y*   46272 46272  SU
```

Any suggestions for how to work across rows? I work primarily in `dplyr`.

Comment: Weird! It does the replacement with `!tagl == TAGLFT` with no problems (for `mutate(tagl=ifelse(!tagl==TAGLFT, TAGLFT, tagl))`)?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the problem.  You want to replace the id for observation 2 with the id for observation 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
  library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
dat <- tibble::tribble(~id,          ~colours, ~tagl,  ~TAGLFT, ~grid,
"6391",        "B*/Y*",   "45820", "45820",  "KL", 
"6391",        "B*/Y*",   "45820", "46272",  "KL",
"8443",        "B*/Y*",   "46272", "46272",  "SU")

updated<-dat %>%
  mutate(tagl=ifelse(!tagl==TAGLFT, TAGLFT, tagl)) 

dat %>%
  filter(tagl == TAGLFT) %>% 
  select(TAGLFT, id) %>% 
  right_join(updated %>% select(-id)) %>% 
  select(id, colours, tagl, TAGLFT, grid)
#> Joining, by = "TAGLFT"
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   id    colours tagl  TAGLFT grid 
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 6391  B*/Y*   45820 45820  KL   
#> 2 8443  B*/Y*   46272 46272  KL   
#> 3 8443  B*/Y*   46272 46272  SU
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

It works in this particular instance, you'll want to make sure it works on the full configuration of data that you have for your actual application.